# WordPress admin login redirect issue

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

**Context:**

I've literally never used WordPress, until 2 days ago. I was also not part of the original setup of these instances, so I can't attest to the original configuration that happened.

**Problem:**

> There are 2 instances of the website main (prod) and another (meant
>   for testing), both have their own login pages, except when I login via
>   the admin log-in screen on the testing instance, I get redirected to the main instance's admin
>   area, which means I can't update the dev instance's content via the admin portal.

**Example:**

- Prod

  www.site.com/wp-login.php    --> **[redirects to]** --> www.site.com/wp-admin/
- Dev

  webdev.site.com/wp-login.php --> **[redirects to]** --> www.site.com/wp-admin/

**Assumption:**

My thinking is there should be something (on the dev instance) that'll allow me to specify where to redirect after successful login?

I've been scouring the net for possible solutions, as well as go through the site's code, but as the folder structure is a bit of a maze, and my context is somewhat limited, any advice that would allow me to narrow down my search areas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like the Site URL hasn't been updated in the dev site's Admin. Try to login to the dev site, manually change the redirect URL (in the address bar), and update the Site URL in the settings.

Comment: This could be helpful too: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to override the database URL in the wp-config.php file in the developer site.

You can do that with these two statements:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example:8080');  
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://example:8080');
```

add these in, and map how you see fit.